# OneHotEncoding error when applying to an empty field

Tags: python, csv, typeerror, one-hot-encoding

The code consists of applying the OneHotEncoding technique to two fields of a binetflow file: **Proto** and **State**. I have to do this to 5 files. I was able to apply the code below with perfection to the first two. When it gets to the third it throws the error:

> **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'.**

I'm sure the error's in line: **0.000000,icmp,,60,60.0,0** of the file in which the field State's empty.

I want to simply ignore the One hot Encoding and copy the State field the way it is, which is empty and jump to the next line.

```
df = opendataset()

df['State2'] = df['State']
df['Proto2'] = df['Proto']
df['Dur'] = df.Dur.apply(lambda n: '%.6f' % n)

le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = df
dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State)
X = dfle[['State']].values
Y = dfle[['Proto']].values
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
OnehotX = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
OnehotY = ohe.fit_transform(Y).toarray()

dx = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotX)
dy = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotY)

dfle['State'] = (dx[dx.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x:''.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1))
dfle['Proto'] = (dy[dy.columns[0:]].apply(lambda y:''.join(y.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1))
```

[image]

08-03 Edit

This (below) is the TraceBack when I run the code above. As you can see, the error is dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State) and consequently OnehotX = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray().

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/V/PycharmProjects/PreProcess/testfile.py",
>   **line 39, in  dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State)**
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\V\PycharmProjects\PreProcess\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py",
>   **line 236, in fit_transform self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)**
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\V\PycharmProjects\PreProcess\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py",
>   **line 108, in _encode return _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)**
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\V\PycharmProjects\PreProcess\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py",
>   **> line 63, in _encode_python uniques = sorted(set(values))**
>
> **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'**

**NEW CODE:**
I tried to do what Hemerson Tacon said and apply Try/Exception to the parts where the traceback throws an error but it warns me that it has an error and throws another error.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = df

try:
    dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State)
except TypeError:
    pass
X = dfle[['State']].values
Y = dfle[['Proto']].values
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
try:
    OnehotX = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
except ValueError:
    pass

OnehotY = ohe.fit_transform(Y).toarray()

dx = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotX)
dy = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotY)

dfle['State'] = (dx[dx.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x:''.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1))
dfle['Proto'] = (dy[dy.columns[0:]].apply(lambda y:''.join(y.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1))
```

NEW ERROR:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/V/PycharmProjects/PreProcess/testfile.py",
>   **line 53, in** 
>      ** dx = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotX) NameError: name 'OnehotX' is not defined**

LAST EDIT 09/03

The solution to the problem was to simply add the line **df.replace()** to the code. So when it reads it replaces NaN for the word empty fixing the problem.

> **dfle['State'].replace(np.nan,"empty", inplace=True)**

```
df = opendataset()

df['State2'] = df['State']
df['Proto2'] = df['Proto']
df['Dur'] = df.Dur.apply(lambda n: '%.6f' % n)

le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = df

dfle['State'].replace(np.nan,"empty", inplace=True)

dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State)

X = dfle[['State']].values
Y = dfle[['Proto']].values
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

OnehotX = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
OnehotY = ohe.fit_transform(Y).toarray()

dx = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotX)
dy = pd.DataFrame(data=OnehotY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your code in question inside a `try` block and catch the `TypeError` exception, check if is the case where the State's field is empty and if true ignore it as you said, and if not true raise the error again.

If you had posted the actual code that calls the `OneHotEncoding` to your data would be easier to answer you and provide some code in the answer.

**Edit**

The `OnehotX` variable is defined only inside the `try` block. You need to define it outside and before this block to fix the error. Something like `OnehotX = None` would work. Also, I reinforce what I said before, in the `except` block would be a good practice to test if the exception is due to the problem you have identified, this means, test if the State field is empty.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the traceback. This ( https://imgur.com/a/T3KKFvJ ) is the TraceBack when I run the code above. As you can see, the error is dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State)  and consequently OnehotX = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray().

I tried to do what you said and apply Try/Exception to the parts where the traceback throws an error but it warns me that it has an error and throws another error.

NewError: https://imgur.com/a/paeh6aR |||

NewCode: https://i.imgur.com/9kDQiCW.png  ||||| I have also modified the above code to only show LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder

Comment: Could you edit the question and add those tracebacks and the new code as text? Because external links can break and in the future, another person could have a similar issue and have access to the whole question information would make a difference. I will edit my answer and add the solution for your second problem.

Comment: Hey, I've noticed you're brazilian! Is there a way I can communicate with you via twitter?

Comment: I don't use Twitter often but you can search my profile there and send a message.

Comment: Your twitter is blocked for messages.

Comment: @VitorSouza it is unblocked now, send again please.